# Why we need to fill data before linking in link list?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Data
{
    string name;
    int age;
    string address;
    string occupation;
    struct Data *Next;
};
struct Data *Head=NULL,*Tail=NULL;

//here in my case. i am first linking Next & Head pointer before puting data in list.The code don't give any error but concept is not implemented properly.
void Add()
{
        struct Data *temp;
        temp = new Data;
        if(Head==NULL)
        {
            Head=temp;
        }else{
            temp=Tail;
        }
        cout<< "Enter Your name :";
        cin>> temp->name;
        cout<< "Enter Your Age :";
        cin>> temp->age;
        cout<< "Enter Your Address:";
        cin>> temp->address;
        cout<< "Enter Your Occupation";
        cin >>temp->occupation;

        temp->Next = NULL;
        Tail= (temp->Next) ;
}
```

Please explain me concept , WHY WE NEED TO PUT DATA  BEFORE CONNECTING . look at the void add() function. Read comment
 on input 1 it correctly as for data insertion, but after one cycle  next time on same input . is stop execution.

Comment: Data can update after attaching node, there is no hard and fast rule to update the data before you link.

Comment: You generally want to fully initialize the data and pointer for each new node as part of adding the node to the list -- so there are no surprises later... The `next` pointer is initialized `NULL` so if inserted at the end of the list -- you know where the last node is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is here:

```
temp=Tail;
```

You modify what `temp` points to before setting the data. So all the stuff after that is modifying `Tail` and not `temp`. This also leads to a memory leak.

There are other issues, like `Tail` always being `nullptr` because you need to assign it when you assign `Head`. Also, you are not linking in temp properly at the end.

```
void Add()
{
    struct Data *temp = new Data;
    if (!temp) return;

    temp->Next = nullptr;

    cout<< "Enter Your name :";
    cin>> temp->name;
    cout<< "Enter Your Age :";
    cin>> temp->age;
    cout<< "Enter Your Address:";
    cin>> temp->address;
    cout<< "Enter Your Occupation";
    cin >>temp->occupation;

    if (!Head) {
        Head = Tail = temp;
    }
    else {
        Tail->next = temp;
        Tail = temp;
    }
}
```

Note, you could also set the data after linking, as long as you don't modify what `temp` points to:

```
void Add()
{
    struct Data *temp = new Data;
    if (!temp) return;
    temp->Next = nullptr;

    if (!Head) {
        Head = Tail = temp;
    }
    else {
        Tail->next = temp;
        Tail = temp;
    }

    cout<< "Enter Your name :";
    cin>> temp->name;
    cout<< "Enter Your Age :";
    cin>> temp->age;
    cout<< "Enter Your Address:";
    cin>> temp->address;
    cout<< "Enter Your Occupation";
    cin >>temp->occupation;
}
```